# I had a functioning JSFiddle with Firebase Database connections but not working in Dreamweaver?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dreamweaver

I have a project in JSFiddle that is connecting and reading/writing to my firebase database just fine. When I copy and paste the code from JS fiddle into Dreamweaver, the CSS and HTML are fine but in the Javascript file it says 'ERROR: 'firebase' is not defined. I'd really like to work in Dreamweaver but pulling the data is vital to testing/development.

Is there a step to have Dreamweaver read/write the database from Firebase?
(Note: I added the script for Jquery seperately, all fine.)

Here's from the top of the HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"
      integrity="sha256-goy7ystDD5xbXSf+kwL4eV6zOPJCEBD1FBiCElIm+U8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<title>FCF-TRY</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "API KEY",
    authDomain: "AUTH DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "DATABASE URL",
    projectId: "ID",
    storageBucket: "PROJECT.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "MESSAGE ID",
    appId: "APP ID"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out, and as a novice to web development, I'm going to put the steps I needed to do to get this done so others hopefully don't have to. A lot of this is referenced in the firebase google doc but same little road blocks are not explained and were very hard to research.

You need to use Command Prompt to install the "CLI" that google firebase docs continue referring to.

When entering the install commands in Command Prompt, if you get stuck with C:\users\userID> and can't keep adding the file path to your project, you need to use 'cd ..'(the dots are needed). This will take you back one 'level'. Keep going back until you only have C:, and then you can type out the correct file path.

Also, google "recommends" not installing sdk services you're not using, and I can just say that it ALWAYS caused a failure for me so I definitely wouldn't do it.

Hope this helps someone new to this out there!